# Send notification mails when a spring webapp throw an exception

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-ee, exception

Bonjour,
I'm working on a webapp that is built upon Spring framework version 3.1.2.
This application throws many exceptions (for ex: network problem, field size, etc).

The evolution I have to work on is this:

For every exception thrown, the system should send a notification mail, I've heard about `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` but apparently it is intended only for version 2.X of Spring (see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/)
For the solution shown on the site whose URL is above, the developer mentioned `@ExceptionHandler` for Spring 3.X, but I have hundreds of methods in the system, I prefer (if it exists) a global solution so I would not have to mention the `ExceptionHandler` annotation upon every method declaration.

Does anyone have an idea about how to implement this?

Comment: Assuming you have a logging framework ([log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) or [logback](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/email-alerts-with-logback/)) this can quite easily be configured in there. No need to do anything in your application. Also I believe putting that, as logic, in your application is the wrong approach. Monitoring and signaling shouldn't be part of the application but a separate part based on logging or metrics from your application.

Comment: There is btw nothing preventing you from using the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` in a Spring 3 environment. Annotations are an option but that doesn't mean they are required to use!.

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

> After throwing advice runs when a matched method execution exits by
>   throwing an exception. It is declared using the @AfterThrowing
>   annotation:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;

@Aspect
public class AfterThrowingExample {

  @AfterThrowing("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()")
  public void doRecoveryActions() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

More at:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html